# Cast Realm List to Array without expliciting its type

Tags: swift, realm

When using `Mirror` to iterate through an `Object` properties, how do I cast a `List<Object>` to Swift primitive array type `[Object]`?

My code is structured as follow

```
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: myObjecy)

    for (_, attr) in mirror.children.enumerated() {
        let object = attr.value

        if let encodableAttribute = attr.value as? [Protocol] {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Here `attr.value` has type `Any`. I would like that when this value is from kind `List<Object>`, to cast it as it is in the `if` statement, but without casting it to `List` before, because I want it to be generic to work with normal arrays as well.